# How to Block End Users from running Scripts against my Farm

Tags: 2013, powershell, web-services, governance

We have been experiencing issue where users are running Powershell Scripts against our production Farm using Web services, provided site owners access provileges they have. we want to set some sort of Block and Check mechanism from farm level to block users to be able to do that. Are there any suggested way to go on this pathway, can community suggest me any sorts of solutions here. I dont want users to be running malicious codes or scripts against my farm. Any suggestions would be very beneficial.

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

You need to removethe  `Use Remote Interfaces`  This permission gives users access to several types of remote interfaces including SharePoint Designer, Web services and the Web Distributed Authoring and Versioning, or WebDAV, publishing interface.

The **Use Remote Interfaces permission** is part of all of the default permission levels except **LimitedAccess** and **Restricted Read**.

What you need, you have to update all other permission levels and remove this permission from it.

Note: it will also disable any client integration features as these depend on the APIs,

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2592376

Comment: We implement Features Such as Open in Windows Explorer to copy multiple files at once which actively uses Client Integration Features and other features related to webservices. Therefore the suggested option would not work on my case. Is there any other ways to properly secure our environment against such practices?